# WireGuard slow routing?

Tags: networking, routing, linux-networking, forwarding, wireguard

I've got a setup as depicted in the picture. The problem is catastrophic speed when using routing.

- All WireGuard interfaces MTU = 1420.
- (1), (2) are debian servers. (3) is windows machine.
- The only setup done on (2) is net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
- CPU and RAM usage on all machines is about 5%
- Bandwidth is being measured with iperf3

[network topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0FDH.png)

#### Update

- #2 is doing routing between #1 and #3. #1 and #3 does not have direct connection. #1, #2, #3 are WireGuard peers.
- I've updated picture to show each direction bandwidth. How is it possible, that #2 -> #1 upload speed via WireGuard is so slow?
- #1 is in Warsaw, #2 is in Ashburn (Hetzner), #3 is VM with Windows 11 onboard.
- I've tried Ubuntu for #2. Nothing changed ¯_(ツ)_/¯

[download/upload speed between each peer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85Ene.png)

#### Update 2

Wireguard IRC channel required info:

- (1) : https://0x0.st/oW4f.txt
- (2) : https://0x0.st/oW4W.txt

Comment: It could be related to reordering problems (WG is multi-core so on multi-queue NICs ...). You could test replacing (3) with Linux or else somehow disabling multi-queue NIC features on both (1) and (2) to see if things improve.

Comment: On both (1) and (2) multi-queue is disabled:
`ethtool -l eth0` gives: 

Channel parameters for eth0:
Pre-set maximums:
RX:             n/a
TX:             n/a
Other:          n/a
Combined:       1
Current hardware settings:
RX:             n/a
TX:             n/a
Other:          n/a
Combined:       1

Comment: Just to check all bases, what about testing with Linux as (3)? And also lowering MTU even lower than 1420? Anyway I don't have other ideas.

Comment: @A.B. There is some update on the issue. I've tested it with linux hosts: where all 1 - 3 hosts are linux machines with up to 200 Mbps speed without VPN. VPN speed between peers is like 100 Mpbs. VPN routing speed is still incredibly low :(

Comment: Furthermore there is related topic on Reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/WireGuard/comments/xhv2kw/slow_routing/

Comment: Are you use ipv6? Try to disable it everywhere

Comment: Cant figure out from your discription: do you have two tunnels - first between 1 and 2 and second netween 2 and 3? Or just one tunnel between 1 and 2?

Comment: Did you see fragmented packets on 1 and 3?

Comment: Try GRE tunnel between 1 and 2 instead of wg

Comment: What rtt between 1 and 2, 2 and 3, 1 and 3?

Comment: Iperf udp datagram default size of 1470 bytes. You have 1420 - fragmentation, lower iperf datagram size to 1400

Comment: What mtu iperf reports after test?

Comment: On 2 clean up nftables ruleset to nothing like on 1